# How to approximate this nasty exponential function with an integral?

Tags: integration, taylor-expansion, approximation, approximation-theory

What is the best way to approximate a function of the following form,

$$ \text{exp}\left(-\int_{y}^{+\infty} f(x)\ dx \right)$$

Any approximation to this, does taylor series work?
The reason I am doing so is because $f(x)$ cannot be integrated in closed form.

If the form of $f(x)$ is needed then I will edit my question and write it down.

Appreciate any advice.

Comment: Can you write yor integral as $\exp(-N\int_y^{\infty}f(x)dx)$. ?

Comment: what is N? @tired

Comment: some constant which we may send to zero or infinity...

Comment: Nope I cantt @tired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the improper integral exists, your function can be written as

$$F(y) = C \exp\left(\int_0^y f(x)\; dx\right)$$
where $C = \exp(-\int_0^\infty f(x)\; dx)$.
Assuming the required derivatives exist, the Taylor series of $F(y)$ around $y=0$ starts

$$ F(y) = C + C f(0)\; y + \dfrac{C}{2} \left( f'(0) + f(0)^2\right) y^2 + 
\dfrac{C}{6} \left( f''(0) + 3 f(0) f'(0) + f(0)^3\right) y^3 + \ldots $$

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks thats a great approximation however not even $C$ is integrable in my case. I was hoping to approximate the integral and not have to deal with it.

Comment: Not integrable?  Do you mean the integral doesn't exist, or that you don't know the integral?

Comment: If you don't know the integral and want to approximate it, then we'd really have to know more about $f$.

Comment: $f(x) = (1-\frac{1}{1+sx^{-1}}) \text{exp}(-x^{0.5})$ for some positive s !

Comment: $\int_0^\infty f(x)\; dx = \pi \,\sin \left( \sqrt {s} \right) s-2\,\cos \left( \sqrt {s}
 \right) {\rm Ci} \left( \sqrt {s} \right) s-2\,{\rm Si} \left( \sqrt 
{s} \right) \sin \left( \sqrt {s} \right) s
$ where Ci and Si are the cosine-integral and sine-integral functions <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral>

Comment: Can you please show me how you arrived to this?

Comment: I used Maple...

Comment: Thanks, I have used Maple however it doesnt give me a result, did you use the int function in Maple?

Comment: int((1-1/(1+s/x))*exp(-x^(1/2)),x=0..infinity) assuming s > 0;
simplify(expand(evalc((%)))) assuming s > 0;